# I saw an article like this, but there is some part I can't understand

Tags: meaning, headlinese

I saw an article whose title is the following one.

> Google hits wall in Korea, says will comply with local rule.

Is there an omitted word before *says*, for example the subject or a  conjunction?

Answer (score 3):

It is a headline. They frequently sacrifice grammar for brevity. Moreover, this headline utilizes a metaphor

> Google hits wall

is not grammatical and should say

> Google hits a wall

That is a metaphor meaning

> Google has been prevented from doing something (as though a car had collided with a stone wall and brought to a stop)

This is followed by another grammatical error: “says” should be proceeded with “and Google.”

The meaning is presumably this:

> Google agrees to comply with Korea’s rule after efforts to be exempted failed.

Headlines are terrible examples of English. Read the article.

Comment: Thgese are not grammatical "errors": they follow the different grammar of [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)